# Powershell List Active HTTP Requests

Tags: iis, powershell

In Windows 2008 there is APPCMD which can be used as so:

```
appcmd list request
appcmd list request /apppool.name:DefaultAppPool
```

Is there a way to accomplish this in Powershell?

Comment: did you tried ***Get-WebRequest*** ?

Answer (score 6):

There is a way.

I use the following:

```
Get-Website | where {$_.name -eq $webSite} | Get-WebRequest
```

The variable `$webSite` is just the web site name but the `Get-WebSite -Name "SiteName"` doesn't seem to work.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee790581.aspx

Comment: Some use need to run `Import-Module WebAdministration` bevor execute IIS cmdlets like `Get-Website`.

Comment: I tried this with PowerShell Core (6.2.0) but unfortunately many IIS administration cmdlets do not exist there yet, and there is no support for the `WebAdministration` module, or the later `IISAdministration` module.

Comment: I was trying to run this in a container and needed to install the Request Monitor Windows feature first: `Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName IIS-RequestMonitor`